# Apache Rewrite Rule and POST Data

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vps

I have successfully installed a URL Rewrite policy, which I have included below (.htaccess):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^rest/([\w\d~%.:_\/-]+)$ controllers/rest_api.php?params=$1&v=t [NC]
```

However, it is losing the POST data. I have seen other questions solve this by changing the FULL url to a relative one (which mine is), or by installing something like MOD_PROXY. However, I would like to keep this without the need to install additional apache mods if possible. Ive also tried [NC,L] too.

Any ideas? The Rewrite is functioning, but I'm just losing the POST data. It is, however, keeping POST as the request_method. It is also keeping the headers, as it passes the authentication block of the API I am building.

Comment: What URL do you see in your browser and what do you want to rewrite it to?

Comment: I'm using PAW (a REST API program I bought for ease of use) but my intentions were to keep the URL the rewritten one (rather than redirect). I put {domain}/rest/queue/new.xml and it hits the page for output (so the route is working, I'm just losing the POST data). I do have the headers working even if using the rewrite. Is there anything specific I can provide to help?

Comment: POST data doesn't get lost in internal rewrite like shown above. Are there more rule also?

Comment: Nope. Thats the whole .htaccess file (and the only .htaccess file). I am confirming that the method is POST with REQUEST_METHOD yielding "post", but when I do print_r($_POST) I get an empty array. I do print_r($_REQUEST) to get all POST and GET (incase the program I use merged them or something) and I only get the two from the rewrite rule (params and v).

Comment: Can I provide any values from a phpinfo() to help?

Comment: Yes that will be a great start for investigation.

Comment: Which values would you like? I don't think I can post all of them. I don't have enough characters.

Comment: You can post values of `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, `SCRIPT_FILENAME` `SCRIPT_URI`, `HTTP_HOST` etc

Comment: The header "HTTP Request" is "POST /rest/queue/submit.xml?locations=this%20is%20a%20test HTTP/1.1". The "REQUEST_METHOD" is "POST". The "SCRIPT_FILENAME" is "/var/www/controllers/rest_api.php". The "REQUEST_URI" is "/rest/queue/submit.xml?locations=this%20is%20a%20test". Anything interesting here?

Comment: Could Apache not be forwarding the POST vars to it because its extension is XML?

Comment: Is `DOCUMENT_ROOT` set as `/var/www/`?

Comment: Yes. Technically no trailing slash (if it matters) but yes, it is.

Comment: Could it be a setting for cross-domain scripting? It technically isn't originating from the same host name (since my REST program is the origin point, but any REST-implementation would have this same problem). Do you know how I would check that?

Comment: Yes it domain is changing then that's definitely the reason. Within same domain it cannot happen.

Comment: I think there may be some miscommunication. What I am meaning to say is that the referrer is not the same domain. When I go to the page, the domain does not change. The request method is still POST, but the dataset is just empty. I'm wondering if Apache (or PHP) could see that the referring page is not the same domain, and for security reasons, dropping the POST vars.

Comment: Yes that is what we call cross-domain scripting right? I don't think POST data will be preserved in that case.

Comment: But it has to be arriving at my server, right? I mean I integrate with Twilio VIA a REST API, so they obviously do it. If we cant use POST, how do most REST-API's function? I think the odds of my server refusing the data is more likely than my script not sending it out of courtesy. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it is arriving at your web server but does it have POST data at the the point of arrival?

Comment: I don't know how to tell. I assume there is a security setting in PHP or Apache but I don't know what it is. How can I test whether its getting to Apache but not PHP?

Comment: You can create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then post your data to it from a browser to check POST content.

Comment: I think the answer is yes. The variable _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] has /rest/queue/submit.xml?location=this%20is%20a%20test . I know it works to login to my application and stuff, so I know POST works for (so far) all but ReWrite policies. Should I just parse the request_uri variable and use that, rather than the full POST fields native to PHP? Again, if there is anything I can post to help, let me know.

Comment: I have already tested your rewrite rule and verified that POST date remains intact.

Comment: But on my server, its not. I don't know why. I'm trying to figure that out, and since I am a better Developer than I am a SysAdmin, I don't really know where to start. I assume there is a flag or setting somewhere. Can you post the settings you think are necessary, and then I will verify that mine match yours? Its working on your server, so that might be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need 2 rewrite conditions to stop rewriting for valid files and directories.

There is no special setting actually to make `POST` working. Just create a `.htaccess` in DocumentRoot as this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^rest/([\w\d~%.:/-]+)$ info.php?params=$1&v=t [L,QSA]
```

Then create `info.php` in `DocumentRoot` as:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And finally create a form named `form.html` like this under `DocumentRoot`:

```
<html><body>
<form method="post" action="/rest/queue/submit.xml?locations=this%20is%20a%20test">
   <input type="text" name="foo" value="foo"><br />
   <input type="text" name="bar" value="bar"><br />
   <input type="text" name="baz" value="baz"><br />
   <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Finally open `localhost/form.html` in the browser and click on submit. It will open `localhost/info.php` and should show your POST data intact.

Comment: First, thank you for posting a formal answer. I can't accept comments as answers. Posting from inside the domain has always worked, where the origin of the request is the same domain as the recipient of the request. However, for requests originating from outside the domain, it isn't. Can you try using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en (or something similar, like PAW I am using) to see if it still accepts the POST? Its requests originating from outside the domain that I am having problems with.

Comment: It works from that rest console also. You just need to send `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.

Comment: Its working now. I added the QSA to the rewrite, as well as downloaded another REST client. Now the POST data is going through and everything thus far is working. I cannot thank you enough, but form the changes in the URL rewrites and the new client, it is working as expected. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out eventually for you. It has been an interesting discussion for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I realize how old this thread is, but I'd like to add another potential cause for mod rewrites to lose your POST data.

If some of your URLs are functioning properly, even maintaining POST data as expected, while others are not, check your Apache error log. Apache may be throwing "Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /path/to/something (None could be negotiated)." If this is the case, open your Apache config file and turn off the MultiViews option, restart Apache, and this may fix the problem. This blog explains in greater detail.

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm