# How do I redirect a unknown folders along with Post and Get variables with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am building a simple rest API and want redirect all subfolders to a single file and pass any variables.

I have been trying to use the following without success.  It forwards all the directories to api.php but I can not get it to receive the $_POST variables.

I also attempted to use P in the rule but end up with a 500 server error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516443/apache-rewrite-rule-and-post-data